# Passing a function to the ggplot density plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, density-plot

I have three data.frames and a string as inputs to my function, I need the function search for the string in one of the dataframe and label the corresponding values in the density plot. The bg0, and bg1 has one column x and and which I used to plot the density plots.

```
bg0 = data.frame(x = c(1.2, 2.567, 0.9188, 0.52623))
bg1 = data.frame(x = c(7.98, 9.867, 4.678, 2.877))
matrix = data.frame(sample_id = c(AA, BB, CC, FF, EE),
                    BF = c(1.2, 2.567, 5.98, 7.098, 10.987))
```

For example, if search string is AA then the program must search it in `matrix` data frame and label its `sample_id` and `BF` value on the density plot.

Here is what I tried,

```
plotter <- function(bg0, bg1, matrix, string){
  if (string %in% matrix$sample_id) {
    p1 = ggplot(data = bg0, aes(x=x,fill = "blue")) + 
      geom_density(alpha = .3) + 
      geom_density(data = bg1, aes(x=x,fill = "green")) + 
      geom_label(label=sprintf('n = %s', matrix$sample_id))
    pdf(outfile, width=50, height=20)
    print(p1)
    dev.off() 
  }}
```

It would be great if someone can walk me through with how to pass the search string to a matrix and then feeding the results into the ggplot `geom_label` of `annotate` to label it based on where it is located in the density graph. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the BF used anywhere in your ggplot code?!

Comment: I wanted to use it next to the matrix $sample within geom_label ()

Comment: so do you want the title to be n =1.2 AA for example?

Comment: No, I want the BF = 1.2 on the density plot where it is located

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

```
plotter <- function(bg0, bg1, matrix, string){
                  if (nrow(matrix[which(matrix$sample_id==string),])!=0) {
                   mylabel = paste('BF = ',matrix[which(matrix$sample_id==string),]$BF,sep=" ")
                   p1 = ggplot(data = bg0, aes(x=x,fill = "blue") )+ 
                   geom_density(alpha = .3) + 
                   geom_density(data = bg1, aes(x=x,fill = "green"))+
                   geom_vline(xintercept = matrix[which(matrix$sample_id==string),]$BF, 
                   linetype="dotted", color = "blue", size=1.5)+
                   geom_text(aes(x=matrix[which(matrix$sample_id==string),]$BF, 
                   label=mylabel, y=.6), colour="blue",hjust = -0.5) 
                  #pdf(outfile, width=50, height=20)
                  return(print(p1))
                  dev.off() 
                  }
             }
  plotter(bg0, bg1, matrix, "BB")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Shirin for the code, But i need this 1.2 labelled on the density plot as in, the label should on where exactly the BF 1.2 is located on the density plot, not as title. so in this case the label should be some where on the green distribution.

Comment: done! you can also use geom_point instead of geom_vline and pick your y to be where you want the label to display!

Comment: perfect! Thank you